# Python Error: can't install scipy.optimize.brentq

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, pip, scipy-optimize

I am using the Python module called [PRECESSION](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01067) to model the inspiral of binary black holes. As it states in the linked paper, to use the [function](https://dgerosa.github.io/precession/#precession.Sb_limits) "Sb_limits" requires the use of *scipy.optimize.brentq*

However, **it seems that my system is not able to download/install** *scipy.optimize.brentq* for some reason(s) that I do not understand. Specifically, as the attached image shows, I receive these errors in the cmd prompt:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> scipy.optimize.brentq (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy.optimize.brentq

[image]
No one appears to have posted this issue already, although I'm probably missing something basic. I'm not sure if I can just create the *scipy.optimize.brentq* module myself using the source code [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html) (seems like I'd be trying too hard!)??

My problem seems deeper than just "you need to install scipy" ............
Since I have already installed it and brentq is nowhere to be found:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to use `brentq`? If so, please post the code and the accompanying error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install `scipy`:
`pip install scipy`

then you can call `brentq` method inside your code:

```
import scipy.optimze as so
so.brentq(...arg)
```

#### Description

`scipy` is a package that aims to help scientist to use python for their research, it has some subpackages that each one does special things. for example `optimize` designed for optimizations. `linalg` do some algebra.
if you want to use sub packages in python you have to import them explicitly. so the following code doesn't work.

```
import scipy

scipy.optimize.brentq
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As the image in my OP shows, I've already installed scipy however the brentq part of the package does not get installed with everything else. I've checked in the Python 2.7 folder on my local machine for this brentq package but it's not in the optimize folder..... I understand basic stuff like how to use pip to install packages and how to use those packages in python code. What I don't understand is the error message I get (shown in the image) when I try to install the brentq part of scipy. So you answer is completely unhelpful since it does not address question.

Comment: I've included another image in above post showing how the brentq part of the package is not included in my installed scipy... I've tried uninstalling scipy and reinstalling it several times to no avail.... I've also tried updating pip to the current version to no avail...

Comment: as i said in my answer you don't need to install brentq package because its not a package, its  a method in the scipy.optimize which is installed automatically when you install scipy, the error appears because its not supposed to be installed. just test the code i wrote the answer, and check if that it works or not.